# Deploying process nodejs + sequelize on aws beanstalk

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sequelize-cli

I'm using node + sequlize js on aws beanstalk.

I've several questions related to deploying process:

1. How to deploy automatically master to beanstalks? should I use some bash script?
2. How to run migration automatically on the production server. should I ssh the server after the deploy and run it manually? please no.

Thank you for your help

Comment: 1. It depends on where your code is stored.

Comment: 2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html?shortFooter=true

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928297/how-to-run-sequelize-dbmigrate-on-elastic-beanstalk-eb-with-env-vars-how-to-ac/44727910

Comment: @Passatizhi what do you mean by stored? I use aws elastic beanstalk in order to store my code.
Do you suggest to use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928297/how-to-run-sequelize-dbmigrate-on-elastic-beanstalk-eb-with-env-vars-how-to-ac/44727910
By adding db:migrate to container command?

Comment: Yes. Try to use .ebextensions. It may help.

Comment: @Passatizhi Thank you.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html
Here you can find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the answer:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

container_commands:
  collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  01syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  99customize:
    command: "scripts/customize.sh"