# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deployment Successful but RDS Migration Fails

Tags: node.js, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have successfully deployed my Node.js project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and am also trying to use a remote AWS RDS database. The project deploys fine, but the database migrations are not running as expected.

Configuration Details

I have modified my config/config.js to include environment variables as follows:

```
production: {
    host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
    username: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
    database: process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
    dialect: "mysql",
},
```

I've also added a .ebextensions/migration.config file with the following content to run database migrations:

```
option_settings:
  container_commands:
    database_migration:
        leader_only: true
        command: "npm run dbmigrate"
```

And in my package.json, I added the following script:

```
"dbmigrate": "npx sequelize db:migrate && npx sequelize db:seed:undo:all && npx sequelize db:seed:all"
```

Deployment Steps

Initialize with: `eb init --platform node.js --region ap-northeast-1`
Go to the EB console to create an environment and RDS database, then run
`eb use <environmentName>`
Set the RDS environment variables in the environment.
Run `eb deploy`
The home page does show up after deployment, but the database migrations are not running as expected.

I am not sure what the issue is, and would appreciate any help.

Code and Deployment URLs

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/wego11ya/Twitter-api?fbclid=IwAR01U9YDM5H5FCV2EoOCdg_ST90rhgXinneniWnoep2lCB2qhNKFZm4YfgY)
[Deployed URL](http://twitter-api-env-test-2.eba-6b8qwcy3.ap-northeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/?fbclid=IwAR1bThSaXNdu3IdJv6DYtA4oNorlY-8AorBAPAmEmcIYxR41f49EcBr0Ilw)

Thank you for your time!

The home page does show up after deployment, but the database migrations are not running as expected.

Comment: you need to add node-js tag and also get the log result from eb logs -a and check the output of migrate message

Comment: @andylee thank you for your comments, can you explain more about mode-js tag that what explicit should I do to add it ?

Comment: i meant adding a tag on the question.  I don't know much about node js so you need to add tag on ppl with expertise on node js need to see this question.  One thing I know for sure is that we need an output message of dbmigrate to answer your question

Comment: @andylee thank you, I added the tag, and I use `eb logs --zip` to retrieve the logs and share it in the following link
[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qiaHePgLQ9sMUZSd6Nk-uKlZn2fJlX6b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like migration command was never run.  First, container commands should be on root so you should remove option_settings  over container_commands from you eb extensions.   I don't know if  option setting is necessary for node js, but if you do put it below container_commands.  check this ansser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827811/using-npm-db-migrate-with-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: @andylee thanks for your comments, I ended up find the problem that the folder name should be .ebextensions instead of .ebextentions, that is why my migration commands didn't work, thanks again.